# Navigate to folder on a server with windows CMD (for Git)

Tags: git, cmd, server, gitlab, windows-7

In trying to set up a first Git project I want to run `git init` using `windows cmd` which I ran as administrator. The destination folder I want the project to reside in is on a server (from my hospital).

I am running Windows 7 as adminstrator.

I tried several ways to navigate to this folder using `windows cmd`, but to no avail.
My failed attempts:

`\\ds\DATA\...\destination_folder` or `\\ds\DATA\...\destination_folder:`
return `access denied.`

Then I tried navigating to the folder in Windows explorer and typing `cmd` in the adress bar I get back `CMD.EXE has started with this path as active folder. UNC-paths are not supported. The default is the Windows-folder. This is used.` with the active directory still at `C:\Windows`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to access opened folder a UNC path (which is over the network).

That means the execution when running through cmd should use the UNC path which is actually not allowed.

Don't access `\share\folder` but try create a drive Z: and map to shared folder `\share\folder` and then open `Z:\file`

```
net use \\share\folder z:
z:\file
```

Comment: The parameters are reversed. It should be `NET USE Z: \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can obviously install the git init into a local drive on my computer, but then it won't be backed up by the server that my hospital uses. Perhaps that is the only option?